# display range band with entire monthly dates on range band

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, charts

I was trying to get the band range with monthly dates on it so that on selecting two dates i.e of this form

1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18

below this range there will be two selecting pointers so that on selecting two values  i have to take data with respect to these two dates and display in graph form. please suggest how to accomplish this task.

i am using google charts for graphs.

Thanks in advance.

i have only this please check.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Range slider</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <p>
  <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
<body>

<div id="slider-range"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question is too vague. You need to add more details to it.

Comment: The question is nonexistent actually. haha

Comment: Pls add some of your efforts before your answer gets downvoted

Comment: I have edited my post please check